# TinyMCE Joomla 3 force paste as plain text on Ctrl-v

Tags: text, joomla, tinymce, paste

My users must have paste Ctrl-V use paste as plain text.  How can I achieve that with minimal core hacking in Joomla 3.3.6 , which uses TinyMCE 4?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to configure TinyMCE Joomla plug-in so that the "Functionality" setting is set to "Extended":

[image: Screenshot]

This will add the "Paste as text" menu item to the "Edit menu":

[image: Screenshot]

To make sure that it is enabled by default, you have to make a small addition in tinymce file under:

```
/plugins/editors/tinymce/tinymce.php
```

Search for `tinymce.init`, and make it look like this, adding the lines related to `paste_as_text`:

```
                    // First line is for Mootools b/c
                    $script .= " 
            tinymce.init({
            ";

                    // Paste as text addition
                    $script .= " 
                    paste_as_text: true,
                    ";
```

Reference: [paste_as_text](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:paste_as_text)

Comment: Thanks for the reply - I will try that when  I get a chance in a few days and bump your answer if I can fit that into the Joomla implementation.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to switch to JCE editor as opposed to TinyMCE, the feature is offered without any code hacks:

- Just head over to the JCE download: https://www.joomlacontenteditor.net/downloads/editor/joomla-3
- Install via Extension Manager
- Set as default editor: ->System ->Global Configuration ->Default Editor ->Change to JCE
- Then go to: ->Components ->JCE Editor ->Profiles ->Default ->Plugin Parameters ->Clipboard ->Allow Paste As HTML ->Set to "No" ->Save

Done!

Comment: Thanks, I have used JCE and like it particularly for the control over paste, but the V3  JoomlaTinyMCE editor is better suited to the clients because of the cleaner and simpler interface and its being the default editor.

Answer (score 0):

I've been reviewing the TinyMCE 4 configuration documentation and searching the Joomla! where to change these parameters: https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/paste/#paste_as_text

Although the plugin does not offer these options in the settings, I was able to edit directly in the file code.

```
sitejoomla/plugins/editors/tinymce/tinymce.php
```

At approximately lines 652, look for 'paste_data_images' and add the parameter to paste in plain text as below:

```
'paste_data_images' => $ allowImgPaste,
'paste_as_text' => true,
```

Now by default when pasting (Ctrl + v) in the editor the text will be cleared without html tags and other dirt code from where it copied.

Test version of tools Joomla! 3.9.x Editor - TinyMCE - 4.5.x 2005-2019

---

Portuguese (my mother language)

Olá amigos,

Estive analisando a documentação de configuração do TinyMCE 4 e procurei no código do plugin Joomla! onde alterar esses parâmetros: https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/paste/#paste_as_text

embora o plugin não ofereça essas opções nas configurações, consegui editando direto no código do arquivo

```
sitejoomla/plugins/editors/tinymce/tinymce.php
```

aproximadamente nas linhas 652, procure por 'paste_data_images' e acrescente o parâmetro para colar em texto plano como abaixo:

```
'paste_data_images'     => $allowImgPaste,
'paste_as_text'     => true,
```

Agora por padrão ao colar (Ctrl+v) no editor o texto será limpo sem tags html e outras sujeiras de onde copiou.